# Why my phone state receiver called with delay after incoming call?

Tags: android, phone-call, phone-state-listener

I have registered broadcast receiver for phone state changes.
the problem is my receiver activated after about ten ringing on incoming call.
And I changed the priority for receiver in AndroidManifest.xml but it is ignored.

My receiver code :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String caller_No = "";
    public static boolean ringing = false;
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                Log.d(General.TAG , "call ringing");
                caller_No = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                ringing = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, "Caller "+ caller_No , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                DataSource db=new DataSource(context);
                db.open();
                if(db.IsNoExist(caller_No.replace("+98", "0")))
                {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {   
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            acceptCall(context);    
                            turnSpeakerOn(context);
                        }
                    },2000); 
                }
                db.close();
            }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                //Call received                         
                turnSpeakerOn(context);
                Log.d(General.TAG , "call received");
            }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){         
                //Call Dropped or rejected
                ringing = false;
                Log.d(General.TAG , "call dropped or rejected:"+caller_No);


            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void acceptCall(Context ctx) {
        //setHeadSetConnectEmulated(ctx);
        Intent buttonUP = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUP.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUP, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    }
    private void turnSpeakerOn(Context ctx)
    {

        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    }
}
```